# Xamarin vs 2019 multiproject await TranslateTo(100,100,2000) the delay not working?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on multiproject xamarin using c# for android iOS application,
multiproject, what I'm trying to do is I want to move a button with animation duration 2 sec or 3 sec whatever, The button move from one to another position fine, but not with delay animation why ?!

This is the command I'm using for it

```
await btn1.TranslateTo(100,100,2000);
```

the delay not working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter you pass in is not delay time , it represents the duration of the animation , by the way ,it works perfectly on my side .

#### iOS

[image]

#### Android

[image]

Comment: yea, its the duration of the animation, but its not working on my project , r u using xamarin 2019 ? or using any dll fils or library ?!

Comment: It's just a blank project with simple code ,running on 2019.

Comment: i did the same thing , i open a separate blank project , and it doesn't work ?!!

Comment: Did you test on ios or android ?

Comment: android , i know , its not working on ios , but with me even not working on android also

Comment: is there anyway to do same animation , but working on android and ios ?

Comment: I test on android , and animation duration does not work , it move directly to the position without any animation , but it works fine on ios, it could be the potential issue ,   i suggest you raise it on github :https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 0):

If your Xamarin.Forms version is lower than 4.3, you should update it. Because there was an animation bug in verison 4.2 and they fixed it with 4.3. You can read it from: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7255

Comment: is there anyway to do same animation , but working on android and ios ?

Comment: Although it is weird you can do animation with timer. I recommend you to upgrade your project. While you upgrade  dont upgrade  directly 2.3 to 4.3 it may crash.  You should upgrade step by step. Good luck

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    // called every 1 second
    // do stuff here

    return true; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
});

Comment: i mean its .. 4.3 .. and i try to do it with timer .. but ui freez .. and the button never move with animation